# Crystal input with one pin?

Tags: stm32, crystal

I am trying to make a PCB with STM32 L412KB . Data sheet says it can use a crystal of 4 MHz - 48 MHz. But when I initialize the HSE under RCC option in Cubemx I get only one pin as RCC_CK_IN and no RCC_CK_OUT. However, LSE crystal highlights two pins.

Does it require special kind of oscillator or is there a bug or error in datasheet or software?

https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/389/dm00481909-1799148.pdf

edit: schematic image from nucleo board

[image]

Comment: "One-pin OSC in" suggests that Cubemx is expecting you to provide an external **oscillator** rather than a **crystal** for its internal HSC (which requires 2 pins). An external oscillator is connected to OSCin pin, and to GND (Vss). This chip has **TWO** oscillator domains - are you confusing them...(HSE vs. LSE)?

Comment: @glen_geek Data sheet says, it can use high speed external crystal or ceramic resonator.  I've referred nucleo board schematic using same MCU, LSE OUT appears to be shared.

Comment: The datasheet, table 14, page 56, shows that PH0 and PH1 are the pins for an external high-speed crystal - but these are not available on all package options (only the 48- and 64-pin versions). Which package are you using?

Comment: @brhans its a UFQFPN32 package. I would normally use f103 chip but current IC shortage has forced me to consider L412

Comment: Well, there's your answer. 32-pin package for the L412 has no external HSE crystal option. If you refer back to the datasheet to page 57 you'll see that the 32-pin packages use PA0 as an option for the HSE, but that's for an external *oscillator*, not a crystal. It's labelled 'CK_IN' compared to PH0/PH1 labelled as 'OSC_IN/OSC_OUT' because they're connected to the IC's internal oscillator (which the 32-pin package doesn't have).

Comment: @brhans thank you. Can you clarify why is the other pin connected to LSE OUT in above schematic instead of GND?

Comment: That schematic shows the LSE crystal option which is present on the 32-pin package, so that's a 32kHz crystal, not an oscillator - so the 2 pins on the crystal are connected to LSE_IN & LSE_OUT.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Nucleo, the MCU that handles the ST-LINK debugging has the crystal oscillator, and it provides a square wave clock out to the target MCU. It is the MCO pin that can fed to two pins in the target MCU.